# Sulu CMS: How to get the actual file location of an uploaded image

Tags: sulu

How do I get the actual location of the uploaded src file in the file system (`var/uploads/[...]`) in sulu 1.6?

The Media object itself seems not to give a hint, and the thumbnails are only generated after the src is pulled by the browser, not before.

The reason is, that I want to get the dimensions of an image during page rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In th 1.x release you can use the following class to generate the real file-path of the original file https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/master/src/Sulu/Bundle/MediaBundle/Media/Storage/StorageInterface.php#L42

The service id of this class is `sulu_media.storage`.

This interface will change in 2.x but there you only have to call `getPath` - so no big deal to upgrade when its released.

Comment: This looks very promising, I'll give it a shot

Comment: I did it via the fileVersion like this: `$absPath = $this->container->get('sulu_media.storage')->load($fileVersion->getName(), $fileVersion->getVersion(), $fileVersion->getStorageOptions());`

Answer (score 0):

You've already read the part of the image configuration?
http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/image-formats.html

After that you can access this configured formats:
http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/twig.html#images

Comment: Yes, that will give the processed url, but the file will only be there after the browser actually pulled the url. My question was how to get to the location of the actual uploaded src file in `var/uploads`

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to build.
You need the original file to get the dimensions?

Comment: jep, thats exactly what I need